# Is Careers working for you?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I'm using Careers for quite a time now, and have even applied for some telecommute positions (as I'm planning to work abroad sometime in the near future). All of this comes to no avail. My profile public views shows a "1" (that was generated by me) along with 30 search hits - so, I'm not being noticed.

Is that so, or the site is irrelevant when compared to other career websites? Someone saying what am I doing wrong can really help me.

Here's my profile URL for those willing to slap me with the things I'm doing wrong (thanks!)

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/tiagocesar

Comment: It is working for me; I've been contacted a few times. Perhaps your CV doesn't stand out, or your skills are not what employers are looking for. It is impossible for us to say why you didn't get offers without a) seeing your profile and b) knowing what current employers are looking for.

Comment: Edited with my profile link (it was hard to find it :P)

Comment: @tiago It's hard to find.  We're fixing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things I would suggest having some inside knowledge of how the candidate search database works and how employers use it (also, we hope that our efforts recently to make search a much better product for employers will benefit all candidates in the database):

1. If you can, be more specific listing places you're willing to relocate.  Paris, France is much better than "France".  New York City, NY > "United States" etc...
2. In the experiences section, less focus on what the company/product is and more focus on what your contributions were.
3. Specifically in your case being from Brazil, we're watching the growth of pt.stackoverflow.com closely here on the Careers team.  We currently don't sell a ton of subscriptions to Brazilian employers, but the success of that site may help us bring more employers into your home market.

Comment: Thanks, I've started to do the suggested changes already. I'll complete it from home tonight. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my honest opinion (*please note I didn't read your careers profile, I just see your picture on there*)  Employers probably do not like the picture you have, and turns them off right away. Thus they don't even click to see your profile, hence the reason for you being the only 1 view of your profile.

Dilbert is known for working in a micro-managed, stupid company that does stupid things , and having a very boring work day everyday. Companies don't want a Dilbert, or someone who has a "negative" opinion about office environments. Although I know you're serious about your work, HR people aren't always the most keen on employees having a sense of humor. Please think about changing your pic!

Comment: Changed it already for another one with a lack of quality, but better than Dilbert *sigh* it has been over 5 years using this one...